# How To play Youtube Videos in audio while application is minimized

Tags: java, android, video, youtube, android-service

i want to play youtube video in my application right now i am doing this by using youtube player provided by youtube API for android i am receiving an IDs list of youtube videos they are playing one by one it can be seen in the picture

[image: Youtube Videos]

i just want to do when user tap home button video continue to play as audio and when user return to the app it continues play video . How can i do this ? anybody please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to play YouTube videos in background in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42160968/how-to-play-youtube-videos-in-background-in-android)

Comment: https://github.com/smedic/Android-YouTube-Background-Player  there are some other apps available at the playstore doing exactly what i am asking

Comment: The repo you have linked specify in its readme it's obviously not compliant with Youtube policy. Do you plan to push your app on the playstore ? Maybe you mean to have a floating popup with the video when your app goes in background ?

Comment: yes i will publish my app to playstore

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kc.floatingtubeapp&hl=en

i am looking for exact functionality implemented in this app i have spent enough time on this but still not able to found the solution please have a look

Comment: Maybe [this project](https://github.com/imshyam/mintube) can help